# android при отправке get запроса приходит 200 код но вызывается onFailure

Tags: android, get, retrofit

```
    Вроде всё ок но вызывается onFailure

    postLogin.GetFolder(map).enqueue(new Callback<GetFolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetFolder> call, Response<GetFolder> response) {
            Log.v("Steps","2");
            ArrayList<MainItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
            if(response.code()==200) {
                GetFolder getFolder;
                getFolder = response.body();
                ArrayList<GetFolder_Item> getFolder_items = new ArrayList<>();
                getFolder_items.add(getFolder.getItems().get(0));
                items.add(new MainItem(getFolder_items.get(0).getName()));
                Log.v("Steps","3");
            }
           onPostExecute(items);
        }
        @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetFolder> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("Steps","onFailure");
        }
    });
```

Логи:

D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.168.0.100:8000/api/v1/folders http/1.1

```
       D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer YTZmMjUxOWI5N2UyYzUyZjI5NGE0YTg2Y2QwZjA5YTEyMmNlZWI2NWIwNDkyNjM5OTk1N2Y5ODY5NGVmMDY1ZA

       D/OkHttp: --> END GET

       D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.0.100:8000/api/v1/folders (672ms)

       D/OkHttp: Host: 192.168.0.100:8000

       D/OkHttp: Connection: close

       D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.34-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

       D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache

       D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json

       D/OkHttp: X-Debug-Token: 89b4a1

       D/OkHttp: X-Debug-Token-Link: /_profiler/89b4a1

       D/OkHttp: Date: Sun, 18 Mar 2018 10:42:54 GMT

       D/OkHttp: //тут большой json 

       D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (966-byte body)

       V/Steps: onFailure
```

вот код RetrofitClient:

```
        public class RetrofitClient {

            private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

            public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient1 = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient1.addInterceptor(logging);

        httpClient1.build();

         retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient1.build())
                .build();

    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Post запросы нормально отправляются и приходят

Вывел t.getMessage():

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected an int but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 58 path $.items[0].pass[0].users

Возможно в самом json проблема, а вот и он:

{"items":[{"id":1,"name":"main","pass":[{"id":2,"users":[{}],"name":"Pass","login":"login","pass":"pass","url":"url","tag":[{}],"group":[],"description":"description"}]},{"id":2,"name":"children","pass":[],"parent":{"id":1,"name":"main","pass":[{"id":2,"users":[{}],"name":"Pass","login":"login","pass":"pass","url":"url","tag":[{}],"group":[],"description":"description"}]}},{"id":3,"name":"children2","pass":[],"parent":{"id":2,"name":"children","pass":[],"parent":{"id":1,"name":"main","pass":[{"id":2,"users":[{}],"name":"Pass","login":"login","pass":"pass","url":"url","tag":[{}],"group":[],"description":"description"}]}}},{"id":4,"name":"children3","pass":[],"parent":{"id":3,"name":"children2","pass":[],"parent":{"id":2,"name":"children","pass":[],"parent":{"id":1,"name":"main","pass":[{"id":2,"users":[{}],"name":"Pass","login":"login","pass":"pass","url":"url","tag":[{}],"group":[],"description":"description"}]}}}}],"count":4,"_time":0.064938068389893}

изменил код на:

```
        postLogin.GetFolder(map).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            Log.v("Steps","2");
            ArrayList<MainItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
            if(response.code()==200) {
                GetFolder getFolder;
                getFolder = (GetFolder) response.body();
                ArrayList<GetFolder_Item> getFolder_items = new ArrayList<>();
                getFolder_items.add(getFolder.getItems().get(0));
                items.add(new MainItem(getFolder_items.get(0).getName()));
                Log.v("Steps","3");
            }
           onPostExecute(items);
        }
        @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("Steps",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мне память не изменяет, то если будет выброшенное исключении при конвертации json'а в Java объект, то вызовется `onFailure`.

Так что, посмотрите ваш маппинг на класс `GetFolder`, вероятно там проблема.

Comment: изменил 
public void onResponse(Call<GetFolder> call, Response<GetFolder> response)
на
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)
нечего не поменялось

Comment: @НикитаЯковлев а `enqueue(new Callback<GetFolder>()` заменили?

Comment: другие запросы нормально обрабатывает, так что скорее всего в json проблема

Comment: @НикитаЯковлев ну да, либо json менять, либо при парсинге учитывать.

Comment: спасибо, пойду бэкэндеру лицо бить :D